# Visualize shared uptime of two datasets with uneven distribution of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly-python

I have two DataFrames that both contain result values from sensors. The sensors were not polled in regular time intervals and sometimes have had outages for several days.
What I now want is a visual representation of the shared uptime/downtime of the sensor systems. For practical purposes, let's assume that if two data points are less than 24 hours apart, the sensor is considered "up".

So far I have tried:

```
fig=go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=Sensordata1.index,y=(np.diff(Sensordata2.index) < np.timedelta64(24,'h')),fill='tonexty'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=Sensordata2.index,y=(np.diff(Sensordata2.index) < np.timedelta64(24,'h')),fill='tonexty'))
fig.show()
```

And this gives me *almost* the desired result:
[Example plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0PIv.png)

As you can see, the shared up- / downtime can already be read from the diagram, but I'd like the graph to not interpolate linearly between True and False but rather to hold the constant value until it changes. How can I achieve this most easily?

Bonus question: What is the easiest way to get the up- and downtime as datetime-values for the two DataFrames that do not necessarily share a common interval in their timebase? (In the present case I can probably do it by hand more easily, but I'm curious...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for different interpolation methods:
https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#interpolation-with-line-plots

In your case you will probably achieve the intended behaviour by:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=Sensordata1.index,
        y=(np.diff(Sensordata2.index) < np.timedelta64(24, "h")),
        fill="tonexty",
        line_shape="hv",
    )
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=Sensordata2.index,
        y=(np.diff(Sensordata2.index) < np.timedelta64(24, "h")),
        fill="tonexty",
        line_shape="hv",
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Your bonus question is hard to fully understand without having some example data. But you can think about resampling both time series to common time steps by using [pd.DataFrame.resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! I even remember having had a look at this exact page some time ago but I couldn't find it anymore...